# .Net Core Background Services and Long Running Tasks

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using .Net Core to run long-running background Services and long-running tasks in my ASP .Net Core in order to get Files generated by External running Process in Linux Ubuntu 18.04. Using FileSystemWatcher.

After 24 hours or more, things get worst.  The FileSystemWatch works properly but the long-running threads and background service are not working well and sometimes they stop with no error.

Anyone has an idea about Background services or long-running tasks issues in .Net Core 3.1.

Should I Use Hangfire to avoid those issues?

Example :  This Thread may Works up to 72 hours with no stop.

```
   public class DataByteCollector{

    public readonly BytesMemoryCache DataBytesMemoryCache;

    public DataByteCollector(BytesMemoryCache DataBytesMemoryCache)
    {
        DataBytesMemoryCache = DataBytesMemoryCache;
    }

    public BufferBlock<ByteData> ByteStream { get; set; }

    public async Task SubscribeToStream(string bytesId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Avoid Capturing members in anonymous methods

        var DataBytesMemoryCache = DataBytesMemoryCache;
        ByteStream = new BufferBlock<ByteData>(
            new DataflowBlockOptions
            {
                BoundedCapacity = 8,
                EnsureOrdered = true,
                CancellationToken = cancellationToken
            });
        var byteStream = ByteStream;

        var streamDataCache = DataBytesMemoryCache.GetBytesCache(bytesId);
        if (streamDataCache == null)
        {
            ByteStream.Complete();
            return;
        }

        var bytesData = streamDataCache.Streams;

        async Task DataGathring()
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime? lastDataRead = null;

                var hasStarted = true;
                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && DataBytesMemoryCache.DataCacheExists(bytesId))
                {
                    IEnumerable<ByteData> stat;
                    if (hasStarted)
                    {
                        stat = bytesData.ToArray();
                        hasStarted = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stat = bytesData.TakeLast(1).Where(x => x.DateTime > lastDataRead).ToArray();
                    }

                    if (stat.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var farge in stat)
                        {
                            lastDataRead = DateTime.Now;
                            await Channel.SendAsync(farge, cancellationToken);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await byteStream.SendAsync(new ByteData(new byte[100], "dummy"), cancellationToken);
                    }

                 
                    if (lastDataRead == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (lastDataRead < DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-30))
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken);
                  
                }
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                byteStream.Complete();
                await byteStream.Completion;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                byteStream.Complete();
                await byteStream.Completion;
            }
        }

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(DataGathring, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code. You're asking people to guess what's going on. If FSW posts events to a queue checked by a background service there shouldn't be any long-running threads. Have you added exception handling and logging in the background services? That's the only way to find out what's wrong, which events have been processed or not, which event failed etc

Comment: The actual code is still missing. That's not a thread anyway, that's a *task* that sleeps every 5 seconds. The continuations are processed on a thread pool thread that's almost certainly going to be different each time. That continuation is the code omitted by `//`. So what does that code do?

Comment: If you want to monitor long-running jobs you need to track more than just errors. At the very least, completion of each execution, perhaps even the *start* at a lower level. Processing time is important too. This will allow you to track what was executed when, how long it took and detect wether the processing time increases unexpectedly.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with background/hosted services (they refer to the same thing). Hangfire provides a lot more mechanisms for scheduling and monitoring though. You haven't posted your code so it's not possible to guess what's wrong or what you're trying to do - how is a controller involved with the background services? If you want to post work from a controller to a service you need to connect them somehow, probably through a queue. A [Channel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) can be used for that job, allowing you to get rid of looping

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I have to use Subscribe method .. later on send the collected bytes "BufferBlock " in Response Stream Body .

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : Thankx  ... Channel<T> is faster than BufferBlock<T> ... It works properly now.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an `IHostedService` for this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Because I have to use it in the controller when user request it.

Comment: @TLEJMI the controller should post to a queue that's monitored by the hosted service. I thought that's what you meant when you wrote about `long-running background Services`. A request thread is *not* meant to run for a long time.

Comment: @tiejmi you can register a hosted service as a singleton and use it via normal DI in addition to registering it via `AddHostedService`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks will probably be the answer you're looking for